# Can't access data from a POST call by express saved by Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am just learning Node, Mongoose and Express. I've looked all through stackoverflow and else where, and I still cannot find an answer to my question.

I'm fairly certain this a just a very beginner mistake. When I save posted data inside of app.post, I cannot access it anywhere else in my node/express code. I get the error "ReferenceError: getUsersInfo is not defined."

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose = mongoose.createConnection('localhost', '27017');
mongoose.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
var Schema = mongoose.Schema
  , ObjectId = Schema.ObjectID;

var usersSchema = new Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String, 
    email: String,
    date_created:{ type: Date, default: Date.now }
});

var users = mongoose.model('users', usersSchema);

app.get('/', function(req,res){
  res.render('layout.jade', { 
      title : "Hello!"
    ,analytics: 'XXXXXX'
  });
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){   
    var getUsersInfo = new users({
        username: req.body.user,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body.email,
    });

    getUsersInfo.save(function (err, getUsersInfo) {
        if (err){throw err;}
        console.log(getUsersInfo.username);
        res.redirect("/success");
    });
});

app.get('/success', function(req, res){
    res.render('loggedin.jade', {
        title : "Admin Panel",
        analytics: 'XXXXXX'
    });

    var username = getUsersInfo("username");
    res.write("<h1> hi, " + username + "</h1>");

});
```

Any help you can give me such as places to look or a better way to write my code would be much appreciated. I tried learning from out-dated tutorials and haven't gotten anywhere and the mongoose api/docs don't seem to cover this thing.

Thanks!

**EDIT** 
To clarify what I'm trying to achieve here is I want to take form inputs (rendered in the layout.jade file) and save them to the database (Which I'm doing in `app.post`). I want to then be able to access those database objects elsewhere in the code, not specifically in just `app.get('/success')`. But I keep running into a scope issue, it seems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nodejs/expressjs application, your routes (`app.get`, `app.post` etc) are set up with callback functions that will be invoked when a user requests the corresponding URL. All operations that should be done in a request needs to be invoked from within these callbacks. In your example, you're attempting to access `getUsersInfo` outside the callback you have set up in `app.post`. If you move the code inside the callback instead, it should get you further:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
    var getUsersInfo = new users({
        username: req.body.user,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body-email
    });
    getUsersInfo.save(function(err, userinfo) {
        if(!err) {
            res.redirect('/success');
        }
        else {
            // Send error
        }
    });
});
```

Edit: Answer above was confused by the indentation of the code, which should be corrected now. It looks like you're making a regular web app, so I would recommend that you check out the `session` middleware. An easy way to get started with it is to generate your express app with the command `express --sessions myapplication`. This will set your application so you have a `req.session` object where you can put session scoped objects:

```
app.post('/', function(req, res) {
   var getUsersInfo = new users({
        username: req.body.user,
        password: req.body.password,
        email: req.body-email
    });
    getUsersInfo.save(function(err, userinfo) {
        if(!err) {
            req.session.user = userInfo;
            res.redirect('/success');
        }
        else {
            // Send error
        }
    });
});
```

Then in your `app.get`

```
app.get('/success', function(req, res) {
    var user = req.session.user;
    // Do what you want with the user
});
```

If you were using a REST approach, a typical pattern when saving and then retrieving a resource is to redirect with `GET` to the URL fetching the created resource, and include an identifier for the resource. In that case, your redirect would look like this

```
res.redirect('/success/' + userInfo.id)
```

And you could make a route like this:

```
app.get('/success/:userId', function(req, res) {
    var user_id = req.param('userId');
    users.findById(user_id, function(err, user) {
        // user is available here. Add it to the template context and render it.
    });
});
```

The syntax `:userId` in the uri indicates a path variable named `userId` which will be available in `req.params`.

But if you're writing a regular web application, I would recommend the first approach using the session middleware.

Comment: `getUsersInfo = new users({})` & `getUsersInfo.save` where always inside of the app.post as far as I knew. Thank you for cleaning up my ugly `.save()` callback, it's a much better way of doing it! Is there any way to access getUserInfo outside of the app.post function? Check my Edit for further clarification!

Comment: Ok, I was fooled by the indentation of the example. I have cleaned up the formatting and updated my answer with some more information.

Comment: First off - thank you so much for the help, I will definitely be giving you some rep, when I can. Secondly, I have tried the code you supplied, I apologize for how messy the formatting was, looked fine in sublime but it transferred weird. This answered one of my questions, the other one is still, if I grab form data and save it to a DB, how can I access it later? I am still unfortunately getting the   ` ReferenceError: userInfor is not defined ` error.

Comment: To obtain an object from the database, you have to pass an identifier to the route that will fetch the entity. Then you will use a [query](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/queries.html) on your Mongoose schema to find the object. Much like the second approach in the example above.